# Which functions to use to test Frank-Wolfe algorithm?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I need to make some comparisons between some Frank-Wolfe like algorithms.
To do that I need some constrained convex problems on which I can test this algorithms. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Check out CUTEst, the constrained and unconstrained testing environment for numerical optimization. https://github.com/ralna/CUTEst/wiki Use the subset of those problems which are constrained convex optimization problems.